# LibreOffice Impress progress bar with square/circle

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to add a progress bar to my traineeship presentation with LibreOffice Impress, but I have only find this type of progress bar, using macro

[image]

As you can see, it can be hard to know how many slide there are in this part, how many there are before finishing the presentation, even if I can add the percentage of the progress. This macro can be find at this link :

https://github.com/dasaki/Impress-Progress-Bar

Now, I want something that look like bellow (sorry, GIMP isn't the best picture editer to draw line or square) :

[image]

If anyone have a solution or a link to a macro that do something like that, I don't want to do that square/circle progression manually, would be dirty and really some time to work on it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, may be not so sophisticated. I had looked to start by forking that repository but end up, writing from scratch.

Current state, it is working (LibreOffice v6.0.2.1). However, Setting are not presented in GUI.

## Setup

1. Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > LibreOffice Basic...
2. My Macros > Standard: New module name it "ProgressLine" or whatever.
3. Select it then Edit, Copy below code into it

   ```
   REM  *****  BASIC  *****

   Dim iFileNumber As Integer
   Dim iSectionCount As Integer
   Dim iSectionPage As Integer
   Dim iSectionIndex As Integer
   Dim iSectionIndexCurrent As Integer

   Dim oDocument As Object
   Dim oPage As Object
   Dim iPageCount As Integer
   Dim oPositionPageMark As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
   Dim oSizePageMark As New com.sun.star.awt.Size
   Dim oSizeSectionTitle As New com.sun.star.awt.Size


   Sub ProgressLine

       'Default values
       'sBulletShape = "com.sun.star.drawing.RectangleShape"
       sBulletShape = "com.sun.star.drawing.EllipseShape"
       'Values are fracture of page width
       oSizePageMark_Width = 0.02
       oSizePageMark_Height = 0.02
       oSizeSectionTitle_Width = 0.20
       oSizeSectionTitle_Height = 0.03
       dSeparationRatioSection = 3.0
       dMargin_Start = 0.05
       dMargin_End = 0.10
       dMargin_Side = 0.03

       oFillColorPageMarkActive = RGB(255,0,0)
       oFillColorPageMarkInactive = RGB(240, 200, 200)
       oCharColorSectionTitleActive = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       oCharColorSectionTitleInactive = RGB(150, 150, 150)


       ProgressLineRemove()

       oDocument = ThisComponent
       If oDocument.supportsService("com.sun.star.drawing.GenericDrawingDocument") Then
           'Load index
           sIndexPath = oDocument.URL
           sIndexPath = Mid( Left(sIndexPath, InStr(sIndexPath, ".odp")-1) & ".index",1,Len(sIndexPath)+2)
           iFileNumber = Freefile
           Open sIndexPath For Input As #iFileNumber
           'First line is section total count
           If Not eof(#iFileNumber) Then
               Line Input #iFileNumber, sLine
               If sLine<>"" Then
                   iSectionCount = Int(sLine)
               End If
           End If
           'Remaining lines for sections: page, title
           iPageCount = oDocument.DrawPages.Count
           Dim sSectionTitle(iPageCount) As String
           While Not eof(#iFileNumber)
               Line Input #iFileNumber, sLine
               If sLine<>"" Then
                   iSectionPage = Int(Left(sLine, InStr(sLine, ",")-1))
                   sSectionTitle(iSectionPage-1) = Right(sLine, Len(sLine)-InStr(sLine, ","))
               End If
           Wend

           'loop over pages
           iSectionIndex=-1
           For iPageIndex=0 To iPageCount-1
               If sSectionTitle(iPageIndex)<>"" Then
                   iSectionIndex = iSectionIndex+1
               End If
               oPage = oDocument.DrawPages(iPageIndex)
               oSizePageMark.Width = oPage.Width*oSizePageMark_Width
               oSizePageMark.Height = oPage.Width*oSizePageMark_Height
               dSeparation = (oPage.Width*(1-dMargin_Start-dMargin_End)-oSizePageMark.Width*iPageCount)/((iPageCount-iSectionCount)+(iSectionCount-1)*dSeparationRatioSection)


               'Place new shapes, loop over page for progress
               iSectionIndexCurrent=-1
               For iPageIndexCurrent=0 To iPageCount-1
                   If sSectionTitle(iPageIndexCurrent)<>"" Then
                       iSectionIndexCurrent = iSectionIndexCurrent+1
                   End If
                   oShape = oDocument.createInstance(sBulletShape)
                   oPositionPageMark.x = (iPageIndexCurrent+iSectionIndexCurrent*(dSeparationRatioSection-1))*dSeparation+iPageIndexCurrent*oSizePageMark.Width+oPage.Width*dMargin_Start
                   oPositionPageMark.y = oPage.Height-oPage.Width*dMargin_Side-oSizePageMark.Height
                   oShape.Size = oSizePageMark
                   oShape.Position = oPositionPageMark
                   oShape.LineStyle = none
                   If (iPageIndexCurrent=iPageIndex) Then
                       oShape.FillColor = oFillColorPageMarkActive
                   Else
                       oShape.FillColor = oFillColorPageMarkInactive
                   End If
                   oShape.Name = "Progress Line RS_" + (iPageIndex+1)+"_"+(iPageIndexCurrent+1)
                   oPage.add(oShape)

                   'Section titles, skip dummy title: "_"
                   If sSectionTitle(iPageIndexCurrent)<>"" And sSectionTitle(iPageIndexCurrent)<>"_" Then        
                       oShape = oDocument.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.RectangleShape")    
                       oShape.TextVerticalAdjust = com.sun.star.drawing.TextVerticalAdjust.TOP
                       oShape.TextHorizontalAdjust = com.sun.star.drawing.TextHorizontalAdjust.LEFT
                       oShape.TextLeftDistance = 0
                       oSizeSectionTitle.Width = oPage.Width*oSizeSectionTitle_Width
                       oSizeSectionTitle.Height = oPage.Width*oSizeSectionTitle_Height
                       oShape.Size = oSizeSectionTitle
                       oPositionPageMark.y = oPositionPageMark.y-oSizeSectionTitle.Height
                       oShape.Position = oPositionPageMark
                       oShape.LineStyle = none
                       oShape.FillStyle = none
                       oShape.Name = "Progress Line TS_" + (iPageIndex+1)+"_"+(iPageIndexCurrent+1)
                       oPage.add(oShape)
                       oShape.String = sSectionTitle(iPageIndexCurrent)
                       oShape.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD  
                       oShape.CharFontName = "Arial" 'todo: doesn't work

                       If iSectionIndexCurrent=iSectionIndex Then
                           oShape.CharColor = oCharColorSectionTitleActive
                       Else
                           oShape.CharColor = oCharColorSectionTitleInactive
                       End If 

                   End If
               Next iPageIndexCurrent
           Next iPageIndex
           Close #iFileNumber
       End If
   End Sub

   Sub ProgressLineRemove
       oDocument = ThisComponent
       If oDocument.supportsService("com.sun.star.drawing.GenericDrawingDocument") Then
           'loop over pages
           iSectionIndexCurrent=0
           For iPageIndex=0 To oDocument.DrawPages.Count-1
               oPage = oDocument.DrawPages(iPageIndex)
               'Cleanup old shapes
               iShapeIndex = oPage.getCount-1
               Do While (iShapeIndex>=0)
                   oShape = oPage.getByIndex(iShapeIndex)
                   If (InStr(oShape.Name, "Progress Line") <> 0) Then
                       oPage.remove(oShape)
                   End If
                   iShapeIndex = iShapeIndex-1
               Loop
           Next iPageIndex
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
4. Save it

## Workflow

### Add ProgressLine

1. Create index, a text file, in same folder with same name but with `.index` extension

   ```
   5
   1,_
   2,H2_a
   4,H2_b
   7,H2_c
   10,_
   ```

   - First line is total number of section
   - Remaining lines in this format: page, section title
   - `_` special for section without title
2. Open your presentation
3. Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > LibreOffice Basic...: Run `ProgressLine`

### Remove ProgressLine

- Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > LibreOffice Basic...: Run `ProgressLineRemove`

## Notes

- Most settings are grouped at the top of the script, so it should be somehow easy to tweak it.

[image: LibreOffice-OpenOffice Impress-Presentation Progress Bar with Sections Top Outline]

Comment: where is located your `.index` file?

Comment: @damadam, In same folder

Comment: @damadam, Could I ask how easy/difficult you find it for installation & for use? If it is worth for many users, I may put more time in it at lease make it easy to install (2~3h),  probably get index from included note/outline (10~12h, need reading & testing) & publish it a repository so interested users may add or fork for better turnings (1.5h).

Comment: I find it pretty easy to configure, and also not so hard to use, I just wait a little to deliver the bounty. I don't know how you could increase installation, but it could be worth :)

Comment: @damadam, v6.3.3 makes it easy to export it as extension, then it can be published in LibreOffice site and also installed with 2-3 clicks.

Comment: I had a problem with this macro: only the section titles were visible in the progress bar; the page markers were there, but were invisible. I fixed it by adding a line `oShape.FillStyle = com.sun.star.drawing.FillStyle.SOLID` next to `oShape.Name = "Progress Line RS_" + (iPageIndex+1)+"_"+(iPageIndexCurrent+1)`. My LibreOffice version is 6.2.8.2, just in case. P.S. Thanks a lot for writing it!

Answer (score 0):

Great Idea. I down loaded the Progress bar too. It does give a Percentage figure "x %",
but nothing as elaborate as what is in your drawing.
I am not a developer, and just getting into  LibreOffice Macros.

My Guess is solution is by using LibreOffice Writer Table of Contents(TOC), transformed for Presenter.

If it is possible to tag TOC entries as being 'mile stones', and once reached,
sends an Abbreviated reduced font text box, and toggled Icon to place holder.

I would imagine multi sets of Placeholder templates would have to be made.
Eg 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100. And Template called up automatically
on slide increment, or decrement.

The colour of text and toggle filler Icons would be the tricky part to overcome.
If this was set on a Master slide from the beginning, it would help.

I look forward(ie "Progress"!) to somebody who knows more about macro programming, than I do, giving this a go.